# Firebase (FCM) issues

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, push

I try to built e notification App, on the client/browser i get the token (and "Notifications allowed") with this code:

```js
const tokenString = document.getElementById("token");
const errorMessage = document.getElementById("error");
const message = document.getElementById("message");
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBLjMD7aKrdMx6TBUI_3J******",
    authDomain: "testpushnotif-5bf0e.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://testpushnotif-5bf0e.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "testpushnotif-5bf0e",
    storageBucket: "testpushnotif-5bf0e.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "814573483699",
    appId: "1:814573483699:web:05a5e998bec2f****",
    measurementId: "G-8MM2RNQG8Y"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging
        .requestPermission()
        .then(() => {
            message.innerHTML = "Notifications allowed";
            return messaging.getToken();
        })
        .then(token => {
            tokenString.innerHTML = "Token Is : " + token;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            errorMessage.innerHTML = errorMessage.innerHTML + "; " + err;
            console.log("No permission to send push", err);
        });
```

While send the push with this code:

https://pastebin.com/AGDQZm46

The content of response:
{"multicast_id":1298414817543716554,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/m/gAAAAABfTn0Q3iusZs3EwoTtZb_Duk88b0zs1vY64YOvDox107kfnApq6Y02WpiHOnnkyZS4hsT-gVnvfIw3M3xkZkmZ9qHcsrI1rCgc5_mukv7gdG9Dtg0bQVL2aRkSVtnNRaCqYCXKk7aHdFW4bqobFppCtDSDS1zuugodpnUZ5-1OecImiyTL6RvxfAKuUaj7sEbgv1Xm"}]}

Success it's 1, but my browser not receive the push notification

Comment: Are you testing thi slocally on firefox or in  incognito?

Comment: firefox, chrome not incognito